# Plot SVM model in R -Text classification

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, text-classification

I am using SVM model from e1017 in R. I have used SVM for text mining and classification. So my data is dtm(document term matrix obtained from documents corpus). How can I go about plotting my SVM model?

Below is my svm model I used in my code for class prediction

```
model <- svm(dtm, classvec, kernel="linear")
```

When I use `plot(model, dtm)` I get the error

```
missing formula
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot directly plot an `svm` model -- what are you trying to view? The decision surface?

Comment: Yes ,I would like to see the decision surface(Hyperplane, margins and training data) and also to see where the new data fit.

Comment: Can you post a subset of your data? I am not sure the SVM has been trained correctly.

Comment: The data is a document Term Matrix(dtm), I do not have explicitly access to values, but by execution > dtm I get this : <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 42, terms: 39)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 582/1056
Sparsity           : 64%
Maximal term length: 12
Weighting          : SMART ntc (SMART) **** However by using findFreqTerms(dtm) I can have access to most repeated terms used in corpus as below: [1] "a"    "is"        "also"         "car"     "open"     "am"   "available"    "art"       
 [9] "trend"       "can"          "capabilities" "today"       "high"     "low"    "cnc"          "fine"

Comment: Hi, Could any one please respond to thie thread. I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

plot.svm gives missing formula because when you have more than 3 column in your matrix including target variable plot function doesn't know which variables to choose as x and y to plot.To overcome the error you have to explicitly specify x and y in the command.

```
model <- svm(dtm, classvec, kernel="linear")
plot(model,dtm,x~y)
```

## where x and y are columns you would like to plot from your matrix