# R : Error in plot.svm

Tags: r, plot, svm

I'm working on a project and I face this error:

```
Error in plot.svm(svmfit, dat) : missing formula.
```

I can't understand how to fix it. I tried some things but they didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code:

```
train10=sample(1089,300)
weekly300<-matrix(0, nrow = 300, ncol = 9)
for (i in 1:300) {
+ for (j in 1:8) {
+ weekly300[i,j]<-Weekly[train10[i],j]
+ }
+ }
dat=data.frame(x=weekly300[,2], y=as.factor (weekly300[,8]))
library (e1071)
svmfit =svm(y~., data=dat , kernel ="linear", cost =10,
+ scale =FALSE )
plot(svmfit , dat )
```

Error in plot.svm(svmfit, dat) : missing formula.`

Comment: Possible suggestions are here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910813/plotting-svm-linear-separator-in-r/33204987#33204987> or here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897112/plot-svm-model-in-r-text-classification>.